# Gitlab CI job done with success but haven't run all commands

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have some stages in `gitlab-ci.yml`: `prepare` -> `build` -> `test` -> `release`

In `build` stage, I have several commands.

```
command1
command2
command3
```

But this job sometimes will done with `job success` status, however this doesn't mean that all commands of this job have executed.

For example: this job may done with `job success` with just run `command1` and `command2`

Why this happens

Comment: Could you please provide your gitlab-ci.yml ?

Comment: It always happens at `build` stage.Retry the job may help, but it's annoying
My gitlab-ci.yml is fine.